# What positions should I list under employment history/work for job applications if I've had unofficial jobs and have been fired?

Tags: job-search, applications, work-experience, canada

I'm looking for a regular part-time job.

Some places I apply to require filling out a job application, which includes a portion asking for usually my three last places of employment/work experience.

This is a bit troubling to me because I've technically only had two official jobs, and the first one I got fired from, as I've discussed on this site previously.

However, I've had some unofficial jobs and volunteer positions, as you'll from this list of every position I've had from most recent to my first official job:
getting $125 per month at law office for co-op (present position); volunteered at  law firm for 5 months; worked at a big retail store for 5 months (my second official job), worked for my dad as an assistant plumber for about a year (unofficial job - paid less than minimum wage usually but I usually barely did any work so I got paid more than fairly by my dad); and worked at amusement park for almost 3 months but got fired for mistaking a payment for a tip + it was against the rules to accept tips anyways (my first official job).

What I've been doing lately is listing the following three positions as my three most recent places of employment/work experience: my present co-op position which technically isn't official employment as the employer doesn't deposit money into my bank account but just gives me a cheque for $125 per month; the big retail store official job; and the plumbing assistant job under my dad.

This way I avoid listing the job I got fired from, which I feel much more comfortable doing.

Is this the correct approach, or should I list my employment history/work experience differently?
What would be a good approach here?

Comment: What kind of part time jobs are you aiming at? More specifically, what industry or profession?

Comment: To be paid with a cheque doesn't make the job not "official".

Comment: @DarkCygnus Like working at a grocery store or a retail store ideally. Maybe also restaurants/fast food but these are not my preference.

Answer (score 1):

You put down on your CV things that make you look good. It's a showcase of your skills, abilities and personality.

If the jobs that you've been fired from don't showcase any of your **relevant** skills towards your target part time job. Then don't list the job at all.

When they ask for a list of previous jobs, then you would state jobs that you've been fired from and "unofficial" jobs.